# How to get a equal hash to the FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile("asdf", "MD5") method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash

Looking for a method or to be pointed in the right direction so I can return an hash equal to the hash returned by `FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile("asdf", "MD5")`.  I've been trying code like:

```
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        encoding.GetBytes("asdf");

        var hashedBytes = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
        var password = encoding.GetString(hashedBytes);
```

I'm not that strong on Hashing so I don't know where to go next.  I always end up with crazy special characters while the FormsAuth method always returns something readable.

Just trying to remove the external dependency to FormAuthentication from some internal business classes.

Comment: For the record, this is NOT a good way to store a password hash.  See [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/39623) and, if need be my answer to [Drop in replacement for FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13527277/1967612) which details options on how to transition from this to PBKDF2, all in .NET - essentially, either transition everything to RFC2898DeriveBytes(pw,salt,iterations), everything to RFC2898DeriveBytes(HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(pw, “MD5”),salt,iterations), or upgrade users as they log in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the reflector's output:

**Your problem is not using UTF8**

```
public static string HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(string password, string passwordFormat)
{
    HashAlgorithm algorithm;
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    if (passwordFormat == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("passwordFormat");
    }
    if (StringUtil.EqualsIgnoreCase(passwordFormat, "sha1"))
    {
        algorithm = SHA1.Create();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!StringUtil.EqualsIgnoreCase(passwordFormat, "md5"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("InvalidArgumentValue", new object[] { "passwordFormat" }));
        }
        algorithm = MD5.Create();
    }
    return MachineKeySection.ByteArrayToHexString(algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)), 0);
}
```

So here is your updated code:

```
    encoding.GetBytes("asdf");

    var hashedBytes = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
    var password = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashedBytes);
```

Answer (score 6):

After some Googling, I changed @Pieter's code to make it independent of the System.Web

```
return string.Join("",
  new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(
    new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password))).Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is derived from your answers:

This method in .NET is equivalent to sha1 in php:

```
string sha1Hash(string password)
{
    return string.Join("", SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)).Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))).ToLower();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is the actual code used to create the password with that method:

```
System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.ByteArrayToHexString(
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)
    ), 0
);
```

Comment: But now you are re-introducing the dependency on System.Web.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string sha1Hash(string password)
    {
           return string.Join("", MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password)).Select(s => s.ToString("x2"))).ToLower();

    }
```

Comment: An alternative method

Answer (score 0):

```
Random randomText = new Random();
 var algorithm = System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create("MD5");
 byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(randomText.Next())));

// ToString("x2")  converts byte in hexadecimal value
string encryptedVal = string.Concat(hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))).ToUpperInvariant();
```